# When indexing a nested object: TypeScript (7053): Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type X can't be used to index type Y

Tags: typescript

I am struggling with a TypeScript issue `(7053): Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type X can't be used to index type Y` when trying to index a nested object. Seems like TypeScript cannot properly establish the connection between a parent key and subkey as defined in `TheTypeKeysCombined` or even `AllowedKeySubkeyPairs`.

There is something with the return value of `.split()` method, since manually typing the parent key and subkey works. But I can't figure out what I'm missing here.

The construct `TheTypeKeysCombined` e.g. `'second.secondThird'` is required to remain in this format, and then the usage of `.split()` method is just an idea to extract the parent key and subkey when `TheTypeKeysCombined` is passed.

TypeScript [playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=46&ssc=6&pln=46&pc=27#code/MYewdgzgLgBGCm14BMDC5oHkBGArGAvDAN4BQMFMAZgJYBO0AXCeZW7Q1AGL1MwDkHaD04A1AIYAbfgBpWFAL5y2EeKDDJmZNirXhkIvv1XqDvKBOnKdFE-oDKejc2NPkj05dnyddjQBUAC3pNAT9kIJCvaxtwrhAAVzooQJc4xOTA6J8lHxSQrR82fLozThcSsuhsmwpKj30K4NLDCylvNlyFGHEIGHVoAG5SUigATwAHeBgg+H9J6aJxqZAqOEQoFHRIKBxcYeXp2fmpgGl4Mb6iYgBtU5gaMBgAawvVmcC5hYBdZlex97HBZ3b4KA4LD5fM4XCDoAC22EeKEIJDuDye-0BnxO8HOl1+MAABgASYinBQAOlJQOhlxBCkJChumLWNNxMO+wwA9FyYIdITi8bCQAikcgUQAiIRQCnS1oSmAAHxgEvCFLi5gVytVbnVbgaGi1KrV4UipSNOtMetM8SSKQtlQplXlSpVjvqbglIx5MAAMvAoMYYBBxGMYAB3aYAcwDwZFAeCYCjMEkNFefOCEEYpAGsDhYwAigl4HQw8w2UL4YiEOKiK4rabmsh+MNSD7-KWYABiACMOYwsGZF19ADdJD2APo9mQvYdjycAJm+KPzRZLY3VE1TUAAFPwKfwAJTDXMwfOWHsohBINADvZDsaj8dT74Pp+Lzlt3kAWgAfDAAFFJHgOF4DAWAaDhLcaGAGgoEkMNAl6Honn4cQwDGfg+QhbA1HEBJVBgeAAA8JjoRAIBocAYHefljCgOhHijLDgHQ-hYFwmACORKAQHRZASOwqYYApUTvV5DswzhdCEikBD+x2GA3zHABZKcZ3+J81KXGBmAAQUkSQQEjZA8XsBJsH+AAFcReBRG5630WQwjcM1m0-U9zykFSrw2LY7zwZTJDUntX001SJyXbkf3-AB1EA6GeCAZ2wBJYAASXWZE6HEFISwjODAiJVdi1LTdtz3A9D0JcSZk7LsFwU6AlPCyQF3U2dHzHdqdKIEr13KuDKqPE8BzPMZLAXXyb22LBAta9rL2QlkBR+IKep6PoVrZB8sSheBvk-H0-xgeLEr6VLYEJLy2sJB4+loiF+AQEcS34WrJO7ABmJrB1ar6Ov+yLlz6wtSo3CBoN3fcj02lq3lZbEFg0hHVqmXbEf2w7RsUm6vumzZbx2e8gdCoKAair8YBOs6kpgS64cjQyZzy4qJqkL67poB61jol63pSvDiyJIGFy5nmhOmZ74Feuh3qpz6uwAFlGCEDKMkyzIs6zbIYFFbnuR5Or2nECQNqaje2pH0dOQ7dKU04Z1OJcmSt-aQVBDG0YO6LJZgdXjJQLXLIuGy7KIG4pU1Gco84eVl2VSPwglGONU4CUE6Uy19BT419U9TOk89VPXKbDPXSL0xc+zjRbUycvE4lSpq+dTVC9Eilvl++GuskJXAbnPvgZXMGBshiqYcPOGA81i5zJDsYw4YHHmpupWCf84n5sH-uyda-vKeO-8gJAsCIKg1NYPgxDkPQgR0Mwv3cNY7iiNI8iIEo6jHuEjv+jYji0xuLil4vxQS-IO4jCgdAoAA).

```js
const nestedConstObj = {
    first: {
        firstFirst: 'firstFirstVal',
    },
    second: {
        secondFirst: 'secondFirstVal',
        secondSecond: 'secondSecondVal',
        secondThird: 'secondThirdVal',
        secondFourth: 'secondFourthVal',
    },
    third: {
        thirdFirst: 'thirdFirstVal',
        thirdSecond: 'thirdFirstVal',
    },
} as const;

type TheType = typeof nestedConstObj;
type TheTypeKeys = {[K in keyof TheType]: keyof TheType[K]};
type TheTypeKeysCombined = {[K in keyof TheTypeKeys]: `${K}.${TheTypeKeys[K]}`}[keyof TheTypeKeys];
// type TheTypeKeysCombined = "first.firstFirst" | "second.secondFirst" | "second.secondSecond" | "second.secondThird" | "second.secondFourth" | "third.thirdFirst" | "third.thirdSecond"

// Let's say we get something like this:
const myQuery : TheTypeKeysCombined = 'second.secondThird';

// Try #1 --- THE ISSUE ---
const [keyLvl1_1, keyLvl1_2] = myQuery.split('.');
const myVal1 = nestedConstObj[keyLvl1_1][keyLvl1_2];
// -> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type ...

// Try manually
const [keyLvlM_1, keyLvlM_2] : AllowedKeySubkeyPairs = ['second', 'secondThird'];
const myValM = nestedConstObj[keyLvlM_1][keyLvlM_2];
// -> Works, but I need rather with `myQuery.split('.')`

// Try #2
const [keyLvl2_1, keyLvl2_2] = myQuery.split('.');
const myVal2 = nestedConstObj[keyLvl2_1 as keyof TheType][keyLvl2_2 as keyof TheType[keyof TheType]];
// -> Works but `myVal2` is of type 'never'

// Try #3
const [keyLvl3_1, keyLvl3_2] = myQuery.split('.') as [keyof TheType, keyof TheType[keyof TheType]];
const myVal3 = nestedConstObj[keyLvl3_1][keyLvl3_2];
// -> Works but as well, the `myVal3` is of type 'never', becaue `keyLvl3_2` is of type 'never'

// Try #4
type AllowedKeySubkeyPairs = {[K in keyof TheType]: {[K2 in keyof TheType[K]] : [K, K2]}[keyof TheType[K]]}[keyof TheType];
// type AllowedKeySubkey = ["first", "firstFirst"] | ["second", "secondFirst"] | ["second", "secondSecond"] | ["second", "secondThird"] | ["second", "secondFourth"] | ["third", "thirdFirst"] | [...]
const [keyLvl4_1, keyLvl4_2] = myQuery.split('.') as AllowedKeySubkeyPairs;
const myVal4 = nestedConstObj[keyLvl4_1][keyLvl4_2];
// -> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type ... can't be used to index type ...
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w1x7OW) work for you? if yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Hey thank you! Seems to work and looks rather complex, would you mind putting a bit clarification too?

Comment: Yes, I will put explanations in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.prototype.split()` no matter what returns `string[]`, that's why just by using it, we won't be able to get the correct inference.

As an option, we can write a generic type `Split` that would accept a string and delimiter and return a tuple of literals. Basically, it is a type version of `split`:

```
type Split<Str extends string, Del extends string> = string extends Str
  ? string[]
  : '' extends Str
  ? []
  : Str extends `${infer T}${Del}${infer U}`
  ? [T, ...Split<U, Del>]
  : [Str];
```

Explanation:

We need to check if `Str` is any string. In that case, there is no point in going further since it's not a literal string: `string extends Str`.

Next, we check if the `Str` is empty, which also stops us from going further: `'' extends Str`.

Otherwise, we use [infer](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) to split the `Str` in `T`, which is the part before `Del` and `U` which is the part after `Del`. If that's true then we put the `T` in a tuple and call the `Split` recursively for the rest of the `Str`, which is `U`. If we fail to infer `T` and `U` it means that we can't divide anymore, thus we just return `[Str]`.

We will need to create a function that will use the type above:

```
const splitTyped = <Str extends string, Del extends string>(
  str: Str,
  del: Del,
): Split<Str, Del> => {
  return str.split(del) as Split<Str, Del>;
};
```

Unfortunately, we will need to use assertion, because `split` returns `string[]`.

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBGCm14BMDC5oHkBGArGAvDAN4BQMMAZgJYBO0AXCeRVXdAGLtRMDkN9KF0EA1AIYAbXgBoWAX1kUI8UGGRMyrGMtXJhjGLx3g93cVMWtjagMoqTfa8ju7zMlkvtqAKgAs66oZOfgFulp66HCAArrRQvo5eejFxvmHylvEBGh4wWbSmgnz5hdDpWiUuDoYl+lDlMAqkcjBiEDCq0ADcpKRQAJ4ADvAwfvDeQyNEA8MglHCIUCjokFA4uD0zI2MTwwDS8P3tRMQwANp7MNRgMADWh3OjvuOTALpM9-2PO5MXr42bSZPF77Q4QdAAW2w1xQhGYFAuVxun2+z128AOR3eMAABgASYh7OQAOgJP1BRz+chxPTkZxR83JGLBrx6fSBNkGEmoUAAPDYoLQYPAAB5LNTtaC0a4Ac2kMAAIvAJMKxfAJdpBbKAHxwqWy1Xi5DtAW0FgAfk10rAMrOrxYfF4hvVxpgpot53tFCYpudGvxxGulHgQu8cgJSok4cDYGDQoAqtSPWdvPLienOdy+fH5ZHtV6YEwzqbWb1OrAIFyeejkHD+YK-a79Tbc8rG5KtTbtQAKFhSn2CyzIZVMSOyACUPqrfNNrYkuoIus0MFo8CgsRuUuJlaz3eHEnHrRN0-rtDn2tpbPLMAh-QAitEQ-0mEzMeCQFCYbWiEYktukiEBS8FeGCwPShwADIAG4SAAjAA+rB8qfNBcHwQATP8RA7tWkzIN2t4Pk+8q8MSvDjj0163uYsFwggSBoKB6zgf0qEIbBrwsWxGGlkAA)